# CSS height of divs not correct

Tags: html, css

I am trying to produce the following, basically a page broken six pieces

```
__________
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|__|__|__|
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
----------
```

But what I'm getting looks like this:

```
__________
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
----------
```

Here is the css:

```
.paginationPage {
    height: 110px;
    width: 82px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#insertionGrid {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#odds, #evens {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#odds {
    z-index: 1;
}

#evens {
    z-index: 2;
}

.insertionBlock {
    float: left;
}

.oneSixth {
    height: 50%;
    width: 33%;
}

.oneEigth {
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="paginationPage">
    <div id="insertionGrid">
        <div id="odds">
            <div>
                <div id="o1" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="o2" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="o3" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="o4" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="o5" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="o6" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

paginationPage is 110px and inside things are height 100%, except oneSixth class which is 50%.  So why is the oneSixth div taking up something like 10% not 50%?

Comment: If you put this in a Fiddle, it will make it easier for people to help you. However, I'm going to guess that it has to do with the container of the `.oneSixth` divs having no height set. Since percentage heights are based on the heights of their parents, the `<div>`s with no class should have their heights set to 50% and the `.oneSixth` divs should have their heights set to 100%.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ueAuL/

Comment: The two divs that are children of #odds have no height set, so their height is determined by their content – and then specifying the height of those content elements in percent can’t work.

Comment: Ok that was it - I did not know that I could not skip a level.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brian Ray was right.

"However, I'm going to guess that it has to do with the container of the .oneSixth divs having no height set. Since percentage heights are based on the heights of their parents, the s with no class should have their heights set to 50% and the .oneSixth divs should have their heights set to 100%."

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea.  You just need to get rid of the `<div>` tags around `o1,o2,o3` and around `o4,o5,o6`.  The `o` divs will automatically fit and fill into the second row, so you don't need them.  If you have those div tags in there, you are fitting your `o1,o2,o3` to it's parent div, and that's why they get smaller than you think they should.

See for a working example.  I added a border so it's easier to see.
http://jsfiddle.net/WD79x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method, using `position:absolute`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bN89K/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="paginationPage">
    <div id="insertionGrid">
        <div class="top">
            <div id="o1" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="o2" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="o3" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div id="o4" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="o5" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="o6" class="oneSixth insertionBlock">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.paginationPage {
    height: 110px;
    width: 82px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    position:relative;
}

.oneSixth {
    width:33.33333%;
    position:absolute;
}
.top .oneSixth:nth-child(even),
.bottom .oneSixth:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:red;
}
.top .oneSixth:nth-child(odd),
.bottom .oneSixth:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:blue;
}
.oneSixth:nth-child(1) {
    left:0;
}
.oneSixth:nth-child(2) {
    left:33.33333%
}
.oneSixth:nth-child(3) {
    right:0
}
.top .oneSixth {
    top:0;
    bottom:50%;
}
.bottom .oneSixth {
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
}
```